# NodeJS Issue with Ubuntu server with Docker

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I install nodejs using this command:
**sudo apt install nodejs**
Then when installation is complete
I tried to run some script but has error

[my script command]

[image]

When I run this script using nodejs the error occur

[image]

My ubuntu version and Nodejs version:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall that nodejs version

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs
```

Install latest version of nodejs

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

After this try to run your file

```
node yourfile
```